# How to select elements containing other elements' values as substring with jq

Tags: json, jq

I need to select only elements `somekey` where `id` isn't a substring of `somekey`

```
[
  {
    "id": "abcd",
    "somekey": "abcdrestofchain"
  },
  {
    "id": "efgh",
    "somekey": "mnoprestofchain"
  },
  {
    "id": "ijkl",
    "somekey": "xyzrestofchain"
  }
]
```

Here is what I have tried that comes closest to a success:

```
jq .[] | select(.somekey|contains(.id)|not)
```

The result should be:

```
[
  {
    "id": "efgh",
    "somekey": "mnoprestofchain"
  },
  {
    "id": "ijkl",
    "somekey": "xyzrestofchain"
  }
]
```

But instead, I have this error:

> jq: error (at :206): Cannot index string with string "issuers"

I can only match strings in `contains()` or `test()` functions.
How can I match another element of the array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.somekey | contains(.id)` expects `.somekey.id` to be valid. You can use an assignment to store `.id` *before* you dive into `.somekey` to avoid this:

```
jq 'map(select(.id as $id | .somekey | contains($id) | not))'
```

Comment: I don't believe there's any real need to use `inputs` (and `-n` with it) here; you can just use `[.[] | ...]`, which can be shortened to `map(...)`.

Comment: It's working, without `inputs` and `-n` option (doesn't fit my real usecase), but the mechanic is there. Thank you!